# How can i get an 'number' input in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make a basic calculator in 'discord.js', but the calculating command doesn't work. Main input command is ':hiz'. When someone types something like ':hiz 5' it should add 10 to 5.

```
    if(message.content == ':hiz ')
{
    var input = message.content;
    var sayi = input.substr('4');
    console.log(sayi);
}
```

That is the code that i tried. It doesn't get the number that inputted. Is there an another way to do it?

Comment: String.substr does not take a string as parameter. Remove the quotes. Also it's better to use substring(). So `input.substr('4');` should be `input.substring(4);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `message.content.startsWith(':hiz ')` instead of `message.content == ':hiz '`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Was looking for this easy solution for hours!

Comment: welcome, you should also check out what @Seblor said.